# Live server not changing after updating my CSS in VSC

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code (VSC) to practice on. When I update my index.html file, the live server will change. When I update my style.css file, the live server will not change. Is something wrong with the way I'm doing CSS?

My code so far in index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/articles/health_tools/12_powerhouse_vegetables_slideshow/intro_cream_of_crop.jpg" 
            alt="logo" 
            class="logo-image">
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#How">How it's Done</a>
            <a href="#Available">Available</a>
            <a href="#Buy">Buy</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Code in style.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(70, 69, 69);
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ffffffee;
}
```

Comment: Where is a `<link>` tag to import `style.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue 1

Import `style.css` with `<link>` tag inside `<head>` tag. For exapmle,

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

### Issue 2

Maybe this is a typo:

- ❌`background-color: #ffffffee;`
- ✅`background-color: #ffffee;`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't linked your style.css file with index.html so that is why it is not updating live. To do that create this code under Meta tag.

hope it resolves the issue.